# Creating pivot table by comparing two columns from seperate dataframes using pandas

Tags: pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
d = { 'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      'col1':['abc','def','ghi','ghi','jkl','mno','mno','pqr','stu','vwx'],
      'col2':['ect','qax','vcx','qtr','vcx','vcx','vcx','nhg','fbv','nhg']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

All values in `id` are unique, I want to MultiIndex `col1` and `col2` and get all ids for each combination in `col1` and `col2`.
This is how I want the result to look, kind of like a pivot table.

```
Output:
col1   col2     id
abc     ect     1
def     qax     2
ghi     vcx     3
ghi     qtr     4
jkl     vcx     5
mno     vcx     6
                7
pqr     nhg     8
stu     fbv     9
vwx     nhg     10
```

What I tried:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'])
print(df)
id col1 col2
1  abc  ect
2  def  qax
3  ghi  vcx
5  jkl  vcx
6  mno  vcx
8  pqr  nhg
9  stu  fbv
10  vwx  nhg
```

This gives me all possible combinations between `col1` and `col2`. But I am losing rows from id column which I need. For eg. I lost row with `id=7` , because it was a duplicate.

Since I have all combinations from the previous query , could I do run this to get all rows which have same value in `col1` and `col2` across `df` and `df1`:

```
#This query doesnt work , I am just trying to show what columns to compare and get rows.
df.loc[(df['col1'].isin(df1['col1'])) & (df['col2'].isin(df1['col2']))]
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1=df.copy() 
df1[['col1','col2']]=df[['col1','col2']].mask(df.drop('id',1).duplicated(),'')
df
   id col1 col2
0   1  abc  ect
1   2  def  qax
2   3  ghi  vcx
3   4  ghi  qtr
4   5  jkl  vcx
5   6  mno  vcx
6   7          
7   8  pqr  nhg
8   9  stu  fbv
9  10  vwx  nhg
```

Or maybe

```
df1=df.set_index(['col1','col2'])
           id
col1 col2    
abc  ect    1
def  qax    2
ghi  vcx    3
     qtr    4
jkl  vcx    5
mno  vcx    6
            7
pqr  nhg    8
stu  fbv    9
vwx  nhg   10
```

Comment: I am not able to search value after converting col1 as index. Is there a way to do that?
`df1.loc[df1['col1'] == 'ghi']`